# Pass the view rows into a custom VBO action

Tags: views, 9, actions

I have a view with set of results. I want to pass the view rows into custom VBO action. I saw the below links that already implements this "pass_view" functionality in VBO.

https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations/issues/1180538 --> Drupal 7

https://www.drupal.org/node/2884847 --> Drupal 8

This feature is not implemented in the recent VBO version. I am using Drupal 9.

Any help on how to achieve this?

Comment: The commit associated to https://www.drupal.org/node/2884847, [efaf38b](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/views_bulk_operations/commit/efaf38b), has been done for the 4.0.x and the 8.x-3.x branches. This means that every release compatible with Drupal 9 has that code. You need to install the *Views Bulk Operations (VBO)* module, though.

Comment: The files I see as changed in efaf38b commit is not in 8.x-3.x and 4.0.x versions.